# Show full text of items of listbox when hover cursor over it

Tags: c#, listbox, tooltip

How to reveal an item of listbox to its full extent when you hover mouse cursor over it? Something like following. [image]

thanks

Comment: if it's WPF app, it should be title tag for each option in your listbox.

Comment: and if it is winforms (which I hope it isn't) there is the tooltip control. You should specify the UI stack you're using.

Comment: It was just an example i found somewhere. I am working with winform. Can you please post a code or method for mylist as listbox ... thanks...